# Why are rows automatically deleted after inserting them into attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, editing

In ArcMap 10.2 I go into Editor mode and Start Editing.

After this I insert a new row into an attribute table and if I click on Save Edits, the newly inserted row is disappear. What is the problem?

Did I accidentally start something in the background?

The other tables are working well.

Comment: Do you have a definition query on that layer?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you have a definition query on that feature class or shapefile in ArcMap.

Right click the layer in ArcMap, and go to Properties. Then select the Definition Query tab.

Make sure that this field is empty if you want no restrictions on what data you see. All of the data that you entered might be there, just not visible in arc.